# Java lambda error: inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds. lower bounds: Object. lower bounds: void

Tags: java, lambda

I'm getting this incomprehensible error when I try to use a lambda statement that doesn't return anything (the same code works when the code has a return value).

```
error: method e in interface mkRunTime<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
        mkRunTime.e(() -> p.store(new FileWriter(fname), "Bookmarks") );
                 ^
  required: mkRunTime<T#1>
  found: ()->p.stor[...]e2)")
  reason: inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
    lower bounds: Object
    lower bounds: void
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>e(mkRunTime<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface mkRunTime
```

Here's mkRunTime's definition:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface mkRunTime<T> {
  T execute() throws Exception;

  public static <T> T e(mkRunTime<T> runtime) {
    try {
      runtime.execute(); return null;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      AlanActivity.me.get().ToastE(exception);
      throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
  }

}
```

p.store(...) has a void return type. An example where there's no error:

```
stream = mkRunTime.e(() -> new FileInputStream(filename));
```

it's clearly related to the lack of return: if I use a code block with a null return the code works:

```
mkRunTime.e(() -> {p.store(new FileWriter(fname), "Bookmarks); return null; });
```

Is there a way to make a single interface that handles both cases? if not, what interface definition do I need to handle a void return type?

Comment: Your first interface is akin to a `Function<T>` that permits `throws Exception`. Your first usage is more akin to a `Supplier<T>`, whereas the second seems to be a simple `Runnable` if you omit `return null;` (both with the addendum of supporting `throws Exception`). Overall, I would make new functional interfaces of those (almost 1:1, with `throws Exception` added in). Bonus points for more narrow exception handling, e.g. `SQLFunction<T> { public T accept(T input) throws SQLException; }`.

Comment: @Rogue any chance you could provide an example of the " simple Runnable" you suggest? I tried messing around with return types and returns and could never get a signature that matched the 2nd example; the error message never changed.  As for the exception handling, I'm trying to keep the example bare bones/generic.

Comment: A `Runnable` in lambda form is `() -> { ... };` (no return value), from its original method of `void run();`. So in keeping our "narrow" example for an interface we can create, an `SQLRunnable` would have a functional interface signature of `void run() throws SQLException;`. The method signature of the functional interface you expect, and the lambdas you can assign are 1:1 equivalent. Think of a lambda like a shorthand for the method in the functional interface, which you could implement as an anonymous subclass anyhow (`myMethod(new Runnable() { void run() { ... } });`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is already `Callable` interface in java which covers non-void case:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Callable<V> {
    V call() throws Exception;
}
```

You can define your own, that's also OK.
In order to cover 2nd case you have to declare a separate void interface anyway:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface VoidCallable {
    void call() throws Exception;
}
```

Then the easiest way is to define separate `e` functions

```
    public static void e(VoidCallable voidCallable) {
        e(() -> {
            voidCallable.call();
            return null;
        });
    }

    public static <T> T e(Callable<T> runtime) {
        try {
            return runtime.call();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            AlanActivity.me.get().ToastE(exception);
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
```

Instead of first one you can write an analog of `e`:

```
public static void e(VoidCallable runtime) {
    try {
        runtime.call();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        AlanActivity.me.get().ToastE(exception);
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that works. I had to puzzle out a few details I didn't understand about lambda syntax here. The major realization is that I should have 2 separate files for the functional interfaces and then a single 3rd class with two static definitions the method e, each of which took one of those functional interfaces. before I was trying to make a single functional interface do all the work, and I now see why that was wrong!